# UI automation using selenium - firefox not launching

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to automation and trying to launch firefox using selenium webdriver with dont net and C# for my test cases. Last week it worked fine and suddenly today firefox is not launching at all.

Error:
Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms

I updated the selenium webdriver from 2.43 to 2.45 and firefox version is 36. I still do not see the browser launching. Earlier I saw the webdriver extension in firefox, but after upgrading the webdriver, I do not see it.

I also tried downgrading the firefox to verison 34, but still see the same error. Any suggestions would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back the selenium update and tried with older version of firefox. it worked. Thanks

Comment: am not sure. It didn't work for me. so had to roll back,